# AntLR4 : Build A function

Tags: java, function, antlr, antlr4, context-free-grammar

I've been trying to build a function: `concat('A','B') OR concat('A',9)`

Here is a sample grammar I have written :

```
    LPAREN : '(' ;
    RPAREN : ')' ;
    FUNCTIONNAME : 'CONCAT' ;
    ARGUMENTS : TEXT (',' TEXT)* ;
    TEXT : ('a'..'z' | '0'..'9' | 'A'..'Z')+; 
    allFunction : FUNCTIONNAME LPAREN ARGUMENTS (',' ARGUMENTS)* RPAREN ;
```

But not able to build a tree properly.

**Update1**:

Here is the Tree:

```
  0 null
-- 11 CONCAT
-- 4 (
-- 13 2,5
-- 5 )
```

and the grammar :

```
allFunction : FUNCTIONNAME LPAREN ARGUMENTS RPAREN;
```

**Update2** :

Grammar:

```
allfunction : COMMA | FUNCTIONNAME LPAREN ARGUMENTS (COMMA ARGUMENTS)* RPAREN ;
```

Parsed output:

CONCAT(A,B,C)

```
[@0,0:5='CONCAT',<8>,1:0]
[@1,6:6='(',<1>,1:6]
[@2,7:11='A,B,C',<9>,1:7]
[@3,12:12=')',<2>,1:12]
[@4,13:14='\n\n',<7>,1:13]
[@5,15:14='<EOF>',<-1>,3:0]
```

**Update3** :

I have been tring to build a function : 
`CONCAT(TEXT,TEXT)` -(Input limited to 2 params). This works fine.
I have implemented IF function : `IF(TEXT,TEXT,TEXT)` - This also works fine.

The problem is,
I have to modify it to: `IF(BOOLEAN,INT,INT)` - But with existing grammar for any parameter in IF, it can accept UNSIGNED_INT including the first parameter.

**Grammar**:

Here is the link: 
https://ufile.io/undqs or  https://files.fm/u/7c44aaee

Comment: Please give an example of the input you want to parse. "not able" doesn't help much. Which errors do you have ? Which tokens are produced with `grun <Grammar> allFunction -tokens -diagnostics <input_file>`?

Comment: @BernardK Unable to set Concat as a root element. Also, 2,5 should be different nodes.

Comment: You have the same problem with ARGUMENTS as with STRUCTURE_SELECTOR in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256834/how-to-make-antlr4-fully-tokenize-terminal-nodes/46258041#46258041). And again, what is the input file, is Tree the input or the output you want to build ?

Comment: @BernardK As you see, [@2,7:11='A,B,C',<9>,1:7]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not create a lexer rule `ARGUMENTS`. This is something the parse should handle. And the parameters should probably not be `TEXT` tokens, but some sort of expressions so that `CONCAT(CONCAT(A, B), C)` also works.

Something like this would be a good start:

```
grammar T;

parse
 : expression EOF
 ;

expression
 : expression 'AND' expression
 | expression 'OR' expression
 | function
 | bool
 | TEXT
 | NUMBER
 | TEXT
 | ID
 ;

function
 : ID '(' arguments? ')'
 ;

arguments
 : expression ( ',' expression )*
 ;

bool
 : TRUE
 | FALSE
 ;

TRUE         : 'true';
FALSE        : 'false';
NUMBER       : ( [0-9]* '.' )? [0-9]+;
ID           : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
TEXT         : '\'' ~[\r\n']* '\'';
SPACE        : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

When parsing your input like this, you can simply parse any function that takes any parameter (of any type) an unknown amount of times. E.g. it will parse both `CONCAT('a','b')` and `IF(false,1,42)`. But note that it will also parse `IF(false,1,42,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)`. So after the parsing is finished, you can walk your parse-tree and validate that all the functions have the proper amount of parameters of the correct type.

> Also, Is there any way to edit parse tree?

See: [How to rewrite Antlr4 Parse Tree manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635444/how-to-rewrite-antlr4-parse-tree-manually)

Comment: Thanx for the reply. When i try to build this grammar i get this error : error(210):  The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [expression]

Comment: Yes, just looked it up: `error(210)` is an error from version 3 of ANTLR. That version will not work with the grammar I posted. Use version 4 instead.

Comment: That's correct @Bart. Just considering another scenario, What if I need to limit my functions input to Two parameters only.

Comment: Then just accept 2 expressions as argument: `function : FUNCTIONNAME '(' expression ',' expression ')' ;`

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of 'OR'?

Comment: You mentioned the `OR` token in your example: `concat('A','B') OR concat('A',9)`. It's like the logical OR: `||` in many programming languages.

Comment: Agreed.  Can you please give input to Update 3 of Question? Thanx Again.

Comment: You should do as I suggested earlier: don't limit to `TEXT`, `BOOLEAN` or `INT`, but define an `expression` that matches all these things. Then when parsing is done, in a visitor or listener, perform semantic checks that validate that something is actually text, or number etc.

Comment: So, all we need to check is the number of parameters from grammar and while parsing tree, parameter types. Is it correct?

Comment: Also, Is there any way to edit parse tree? Because I don't much about  visitor or listener.

Comment: Again @Mark thanks for your valuable input. I have parsing tree with my Custom listener.